# Python equivalent of `copy link location` in a browser

Tags: python, file, url

The source of [www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/peak.html](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/peak.html) is the following:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>peak hell</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css">
</head>
<body>
<center>
<img src="peakhell.jpg"/>
<br><font color="#c0c0ff">
pronounce it
<br>
<peakhell src="banner.p"/>
</body>
</html>

<!-- peak hell sounds familiar ? -->
```

I can get the url (`www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/banner.p`) by right clicking on `banner.p` and selecting `copy link location` in Firefox. How can I get this url using only Python?

Comment: Could you please state why you downvote if you downvote so I at least get a clue on how to improve the question.

Comment: What have you tried? How are you getting and parsing this HTML? Do you really want to copy the URL to the clipboard?

Comment: I know how to parse but I don't know how the browser gets to that file location. I'm assuming the browser gets this url from `banner.p` and `www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/peak.html`

Comment: It´s a relative url, which means relative to the base name or base url. See the solution suggested in the answer from Ignacio. It´s more html-issue than a python-related problem (actually, it is not even a problem, but a feature of html) --> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> urlparse.urljoin('http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/peak.html', 'banner.p')
'http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/banner.p'
```